# How a process create in UNIX

Tags: unix, operating-system, dos

Can some one help me out here, it is necessary to complete my assignment.

I need to know,

1. how a process created in **UNIX**...?  and
2. how a process created in **MS-DOS**...?

How is the unix process is different from MS-DOS process...?

I have fair knowledge about Operating Systems.I tried to find better answer on the internet, but I was unable to find in google, yahoo answers, etc...

Thank you........

Answer (score 1):

You can do better than "the internet"...

Try:
[Tannenbaum's Modern Operating Systems](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Operating-Systems-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/0138134596).

Page 735 for Linux, page 857 for Windows Vista (including MS-DOS).